# display combobox in access vba code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using below code in access vba. this code give me the input box to entered the value which updates the value inputed in access table. is it possible to give combobox instate of input box. I can select desise input from that combobox. pls let me know if it is possible.

```
Dim qry As String

qry = "UPDATE Data_Table SET Data_Table.Workgroup = [Workgroup Name]WHERE (((Data_Table.Workgroup) Is Null));"

DoCmd.RunSQL qry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input box that pops up when you execute your code is "created" by MS Access on the fly, because of the `[Workgroup Name]` value in the query.

It's not possible to make Access pop up a ComboBox directly from the query instead.
*(how should Access know which options to put into the ComboBox?)*

But of course you can create a ComboBox yourself (somewhere on a form) and insert the value from that ComboBox into the query.

For example, you could put your code from the question into a function which gets the workgroup name passed as a parameter, like this:

```
Public Function RunQuery(ByVal WorkgroupName As String)

    Dim qry As String

    qry = "UPDATE Data_Table SET Data_Table.Workgroup = '" & WorkgroupName & "' WHERE (((Data_Table.Workgroup) Is Null));"

    DoCmd.RunSQL qry

End Function
```

Then you create a ComboBox in a form (and populate it with options) and pass the value of the ComboBox to the `RunQuery` function:

```
Private Sub SomeComboBox_AfterUpdate()

    If Nz(Me.SomeComboBox.Value) > "" Then

        RunQuery Me.SomeComboBox.Value

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Its not working with me. in combobox afterupdate event i pasted below code but it is not working. Private Sub Combo4_AfterUpdate()


If Nz(Me.Combo4.Value) > "" Then

        RunQuery Me.Combo4.Value

   
    End If
 'Exit Sub
    
    End Sub

Comment: @Mukul: The code in my answer definitely works, because I ran it on my machine before I posted it here. Can you post your current code here? (just edit your question) Can you specify "it's not working"? Do you get an error message? Does the code run, but no data is updated?

Comment: Hi Christian thanks a lot for code it is working fine. but my problem is still tere. Actually I am running transfer spradesheet code. when data uploades in table I wanted to popup a form with combobox from which I wil select the value which is suppose to update in table. Now with the help of your code that combo box code is working fine but I want to auto populate that form once data uploading done in table. I tried DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_Form1", acNormal but this is not opening form1

Comment: @Mukul: Try `DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"` instead of `DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_Form1"`.